# How do I stop charset being set in the HTTP headers of a Railo application?

Tags: apache, coldfusion, railo

I am using Railo 3.0 for a web application (setup exactly the same as [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20120419124906/http://blog.getrailo.com:80/index.cfm/2008/11/12/Installing-ResinRailo-on-CentOS) excellent guide). I have a CFM page that serves up some old HTML files using the cfcontent tag. This content is in various character sets (all defined as meta tags in the HTML). The problem is that all my CFM pages are getting sent out with UTF-8 set in the HTTP response headers, and this overrides anything defined in the HTML. The pages therefore get displayed incorrectly in the browser.

**How can I stop the charset being sent in the HTTP headers for CFM pages?**

Notes:
I've removed the AddDefaultCharset entry from the default Apache config, and this means that static HTML pages are now served without any charset in the header, however this didn't help for CFM pages - [AddDefaultCharset is bad, bad, bad](https://web.archive.org/web/20130711031839/http://ungwe.org/blog/2004/01/26/22:52/)

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, but I have had a similar issue recently and overcame it using the underlying java servlet context. If you get hold of the ServletResponse you can call .reset(), which according to the Java docs says:

> Clears any data that exists in the buffer as well as the status code and **headers**.

You'll need to rewrite ALL the headers from scratch, but it will clear the rogue charset header.

```
<cfset objResponse = GetPageContext().getResponse()>
<cfset objResponse.reset()>
```

This works in Railo. In CF (Adobe) I think you need to call getResponse() twice to get hold of the appropriate response object.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: `GetPageContext().getResponse().reset()` works in ColdFusion in CFM pages. Surprisingly, the character set was not being set in pages served from ColdFusion REST end-points.

Comment: Adding reset() to response worked for me, previously the Content-Type header was returning "image/png;charset=utf-8"....

Answer (score 0):

what charset are you trying to send the pages out as? you can force the charset of the page a couple of ways:

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="windows-1252">
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_13.html#2962107

```
<cfheader name="charset" value="windows-1252">
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_g-h_07.html#3989067

Comment: The documents are various charsets (e.g windows-1252, us-ascii ..), which are defined in the HTML meta tag. What I am hoping to do is not send anything about charset in the HTTP Header, and leave it to the browser to get it from the HTML.

Comment: this sounds more like an apache problem then a coldfusion (railo) one. why don't you try taking railo out of the picture and see what happens. pull up one of the cfm templates that are giving you the problem in your browser and then view the source, copy and paste it into an html file. save that, and call that from your browser. see what charset is sent back to you from apache at that point.